# Does numpy.bincount support numpy.float128 type weights?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

Here is a sample code using numpy.bincount

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0], dtype=np.float128)
b = np.array([1, 2, 0], dtype=np.int)
c = np.bincount(b, weights=a)
```

If run it, I get the following error report:

```
----> 1 c = np.bincount(b, weights=a)
TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('float128') to dtype('float64') according to the rule 'safe'
```

Is it a bug of `np.bincount`? Does there exist any similar function which I can use to work with `numpy.float128` type weights?

Comment: Simply upcast : `np.bincount(b, a.astype(np.float64))`?

Comment: I need to use float128 data in my program, so `a.astype` is not a suitable solution for me.

Comment: This is not directly related, but just some info on `float128`: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html#extended-precision. Extended precision is known not to work in many cases. Do have a look at that link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't necessarily call it a bug, but it's not supported. The `bincount()` function is implemented [here](https://github.com/numpy/datetime/blob/dd2fb142820467993b43b108e4b76d7b2bcfdfe5/numpy/lib/src/_compiled_base.c#L145). As you can see the weights parameter is cast directly to a double array:

```
if (!(wts = PyArray_ContiguousFromAny(weight, PyArray_DOUBLE, 1, 1))) {
    goto fail;
}
```

Therefore, it's not possible to pass a `np.float128` object to `bincount`.

Of course you can always cast it to a `np.float64` object as suggested in the comments if the extra precision isn't required.